# Cassandra Startup java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: cassandra

**What could be the solution for this exception**

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:322)
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.load(SnappyLoader.java:229)
at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:48)
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:79)
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:66)
at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnection.connect(OutboundTcpConnection.java:359)
at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnection.run(OutboundTcpConnection.java:150)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/snappy-1.0.5-libsnappyjava.so: /tmp/snappy-1.0.5-libsnappyjava.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1957)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1882)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1843)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1061)
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNativeLoader.load(SnappyNativeLoader.java:39)
... 11 more
ERROR 11:46:22,430 Exception in thread Thread[WRITE-/172.20.6.138,5,main]
org.xerial.snappy.SnappyError: [FAILED_TO_LOAD_NATIVE_LIBRARY] null
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.load(SnappyLoader.java:239)
at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:48)
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:79)
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:66)
at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnection.connect(OutboundTcpConnection.java:359)
at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnection.run(OutboundTcpConnection.java:150)
```

But the cassandra startup execution is continue. and at the end i am getting exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to contact any seeds!
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:947)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:716)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:554)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:451)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:347)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:446)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:489)
Exception encountered during startup: Unable to contact any seeds!
```

ERROR 11:55:11,732 Exception in thread Thread[StorageServiceShutdownHook,5,main]

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.stopRPCServer(StorageService.java:321)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.shutdownClientServers(StorageService.java:370)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.access$000(StorageService.java:88)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService$1.runMayThrow(StorageService.java:519)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

***but the seeds nodes are running.***

**Machine firewall is disabled.**

I also tried changing default tmp directory. I tried including JVM_OPTS=-Dorg.xerial.snappy.tempdir=/tmp to cassandra.in.sh file but the problem is remains.

Linux version 2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b9.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Apr 23 19:29:00 UTC 2013

please help me.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mention this error here in the Cassandra JIRA:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4400

I had a similar error with Cassandra 1.2, and I fixed it by replacing the snappy 1.0.5 library with the [snappy 1.0.4.1](https://snappy-java.googlecode.com/files/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar).  If that link doesn't work, you should be able to grab that from an earlier version of Cassandra (like 1.1.x).

Basically, remove the snappy-java.1.0.5.jar from your `$CASSANDRA_HOME/lib` directory, and replace it with snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer wrote by Erik in
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201312.mbox/%3C52C1DEC4.2080904@cj.com%3E

You can add something like this to cassandra-env.sh :

JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS 
-Dorg.xerial.snappy.tempdir=/path/that/allows/executables"

I created a tmp folder in /var/lib/cassandra/

so I added

JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dorg.xerial.snappy.tempdir=/var/lib/cassandra/tmp/"

Hope this help somebody