# Snappy GLIBCXX_3.4.9 error when using datastax 4 cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, snappy

Complete error while starting cassandra.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:322)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.load(SnappyLoader.java:229)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:48)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:79)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:66)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnection.connect(OutboundTcpConnection.java:359)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnection.run(OutboundTcpConnection.java:150)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/snappy-1.0.5-libsnappyjava.so: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /tmp/snappy-1.0.5-libsnappyjava.so)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNativeLoader.load(SnappyNativeLoader.java:39)
    ... 11 more
ERROR 17:23:34,725 Exception in thread Thread[WRITE-/10.141.0.21,5,main]
org.xerial.snappy.SnappyError: [FAILED_TO_LOAD_NATIVE_LIBRARY] null
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.load(SnappyLoader.java:239)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:48)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:79)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:66)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnection.connect(OutboundTcpConnection.java:359)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnection.run(OutboundTcpConnection.java:150)
```

**What have done so far:**

- Followed advice from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372704/cassandra-startup-error-1-2-6-on-linux-x86-64) and [compiled snappy from source](https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java#building-from-the-source-code) for version 1.0.5
- Replaced snappy-java-1.0.5.jar from $DSE/resource/cassandra/lib/.

Still I face the same issue. In fact, I suspect those two .so are being picked up from somewhere else. I am on cluster grid so I can't ask them upgrade libstdc++ just for me.

What do you think I could be doing wrong.

Comment: Also I removed .so from tmp, still having same issue.

Comment: I had answered a similar question here.  Did you try an older version of Snappy?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534811/cassandra-startup-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception/19547498#19547498

Comment: Actually yes. But somehow did not work for me. Additionally, I noticed  that I was not copying jna-platform. May be that could be an issue. Right now, atleast it got solved by using latest snappy version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the latest version of snappy

http://code.google.com/p/snappy-java/downloads/list